# How do I add a default value to Confluence Cloud Macro input field?

Tags: confluence

I am trying to add a default value for the parameter specified in the `atlassian-connect.json` file.

```
{"identifier": "title",
    "name": {
        "value": "Title"
        },
    "type": "string",
    "required": true,
    "multiple": false}
```

How do I specify a default value for that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `defaultValue` like this:

```
{"identifier": "title",
    "name": {
        "value": "Title"
        },
    "type": "string",
    "required": true,
    "multiple": false,
    "defaultValue": "My default title"
}
```

Source: [Confluence Cloud global json schema](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/connect-schemas/raw/master/confluence-global-schema.json?_ga=2.81837206.1295740405.1523032783-1691057983.1491669468)